# RequireJS: optimizer generates name for define module

Tags: javascript, jquery, gulp, requirejs

I'm using gulp.js and an optimization tool for requirejs (gulp-requirejs) it combines all scritps into one file. I have one define module with no name but it generates a name for it. The problem is I don't know how to call that module from another file.

For example in page1.js:

```
...
define("map",["jquery"],function($){
   ...
});
define("lib", ["jquery"],function($){
   ...
});
```

and in page2.js I would like to call page1.js lib module but I am not sure how to do it? I would prefer if the optimization tool did not set a name then my code works but this way I have no idea how to make it work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to use multiple modules in a single file, unless these modules are named. Otherwise RequireJS won't know how to relate a request for a module with the actual code that defines it.

The typical scenario when optimizing all modules into a single bundle is that there is going to be *one* specific module in the bundle which serves as the entry point of your application, and then you can just put that module name in `paths`:

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    lib: 'path/to/page1',
  }
});
```

If you do *not* have a single entry point but may in fact also have code *outside the bundle* that will initiate loading modules that are *in the bundle*, then you need to list those modules in [`bundles`](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-bundles):

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    lib: 'path/to/page1',
  },
  bundles: {
    lib: ['map', ...],
  }
});
```

The `bundles` setting I have shown above says essentially "when you look for the module named `map`, fetch the module `lib`, and you will have the definition of `map`."

Comment: Sorry I must be missing something really basic, when I try to use the bundles in my page2.js config, I get lib is undefined. In the config for page1.js I have all the paths to the scripts and dependencies (like jquery, etc.) and the shim, am I missing something? What I am trying to do is like you explained in first scenario - is to have a single entry point which is the lib module.

Comment: I finally understood after carefully reading the docs, you have call "map" not lib when you want to use it in page2.js. But how can I have a single entry point like in the first scenario so I don't have to use bundles?